# How can I localize Navigation Tabs in SurveyJS Multi-Page Form?

Tags: surveyjs

I have a requirement wherein I'm converting my Multi-Page SurveyJS form into the required locale say for e.g., German. The whole form gets converted to German except the Navigation Tabs. Can please someone guide me how to achieve that?

The Multi-Page Survey in my case contains 3 pages.
Step 1. Define below properties to get Nav tabs visible on the form.
"showNavigationButtons": "none",
"progressBarType": "buttons",
"showProgressBar": "top",

Step 2. Add translation to the name property of the page.
"name": {
"default": "Declaration",
"de": "Rechtliche Erklärungen"
},
Error: The code breaks whenever I try to execute the above code. It only takes "name":"Declaration"

Expected Result: The below image shows the expected result with German translation.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gbptq.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [navigationTitle](https://surveyjs.io/form-library/documentation/api-reference/page-model#navigationTitle) page property. It is a localizable property and it supports multiple languages.

Thank you,
Andrew